# Google Adsense threshold estimation

Tags: google-adsense, blog, monetize

I've an electronic music blog with traffic mainly from the North American continent, Western Europe and Russia. Daily I get about 100 unique visitors with 150-200 pageviews. Should I start Adsense or I need to work to increase the traffic stats. Can you suggest another appropriate monetizing option for the given case? How much time It would take me to hit the 100$ Adsense barrier with the given traffic statistics?

Comment: Why would you think you need to wait for increased traffic stats?

Answer (score 3):

AdSense has no minimum traffic requirements that I'm aware of, at least not published anywhere. There's an entire section in the [AdSense help area](https://support.google.com/adsense/?hl=en#topic=1250103) dedicated to the sign-up and approvals process, which you should read.

As to whether you *should* work to increase your traffic, you should be doing it regardless, as that's going to directly lead into your advertising making any money in the first place.

It's impossible to speculate when you'll reach the payment threshold, as there are [several potential criteria](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=9902&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=mqv4zn273h50&cbrank=0) for how much your ads are worth, and when they even accrue earnings.

Answer (score 2):

Completely agree with Su''s answer. I would think, however, that with adsense you will not be making a lot of money with 100 unique visitors.
[stackoverflow article on advertising](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/our-amazon-advertising-experiment/)
Jeff Atwood has also said on his blog before that if you can get fairly specific advertising on your site you're going to do much better than the broad spectrum that is adsense. If your blog has a specific topic then looking for advertisers for that topic will probably do much better.